# Как отправить запрос с js-сайта на VPS сервер под ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, https, request

Суть в том что 443 порт работает по дефолту. И я не могу создать createServer(...).listen(443) а затем запустить программу, так как этот порт или как там это называется уже работает по умолчанию... При создании кастомного порта например 5555. программа на сервере запускается и слушает. Из клиентской части я отправляю ajax запрос, но в консоле получаю следующую ошибку:

// ------------------------------- ERROR:

Доступ к XMLHttpRequest по адресу https://example.com:5555/nodejs/listenMQL.js из источника «https://example.com» был заблокирован политикой CORS: Ответ на запрос перед полетом не проходит проверку контроля доступа : На запрашиваемом ресурсе отсутствует заголовок «Access-Control-Allow-Origin».

**=======================================================================**

```
                   **Вопрос решен, следующим образом:**
```

**// -------------------------- Клиентская часть:**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://example.com:5555/nodejs/listenMQL.js",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    // Сюда придет ответ от сервера...
}});
```

**// -- Серверная часть(Экспресс я удалил, из за его непонятных методов по типу use и делал все на чистом js):**

```
let fs = require("fs");
let https = require("https");

// Указываем пути до сертификатом на сервере. Не нужно ничего самому 
// создавать. Ищем их в своем выделеном пространстве на сервере !!!
let options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/example.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/example.crt")
};


https.createServer(options, (req, res)=>{
    req.on("data", data =>{
        // Обрабатываем событие прихода данных с сайта.
    });

    // ОТВЕЧАЕМ НА ПОЛУЧЕННЫЙ ЗАПРОС:
    // Устанавливаем в заголовке ответа следующую магическую строку, без 
    // которой ничего работать не будет:
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");

    // Отсылаем данные обратно на сайт в ajax объект:
    res.end("Ok"); // Отправляем ответ обратно на сайт...
}).listen(5555); // Как ни хотелось бы но 443 порт, который и предназначен 
// для https запросов у меня так и не получилось задействовать. Вместо этого 
// я выбрал кастомный порт и возложил на него все то, что должен был делать 
// 443 порт. Но тем не менее цели я своей достиг. Спасибо за рекомендации...
```

Comment: оочень много букв, а вопроса нет

Comment: `CORS` ........

Comment: Нууу из текста понятно, что требуется просто отправить запрос на сервер и получить ответ от него. По всей видимости мне здесь не помогут...

Comment: я уже ответил на вопрос, вы невнимателны

Comment: По всей видимости

Comment: Это не достаточный ответ. Я целый день потратил на прочтение всяких CORS и прочего... В заголовке же отправляю Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. Мне просто отправить запрос надо... Я не совсем понимаю что может быть не так... Может ключи не впорядке или еще что... может быть нужно как то отключить 443 порт, и подключить его самостоятельно... и так далее. Возможных сомнительных моментов может быть множество... Искать их всех мне надоело. Каждый день очередные грабли которые приходится разрешать самостоятельно не смотря на то что это вообще изи для прогера должно быть... Но жадность делиться инфой

Comment: опять много буков - не осилил до конца...  https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html

Comment: ВРЕДНЫЙ СОВЕТ: если хочешь 443 и 80 порт - `sudo` тебе в помощь

Comment: вообще для чего это всё нужно? bash скрипт передёрнуть?

Comment: Это localhost на http протоколе... С этим проблем у меня нет. Мне нужно реализовать передачу и прием данных либо при помощи ajax либо при помощи xmlhttprequest... на серверной стороне нужно ключи прочитывать иначе не получится... это ведь защищенное соединение...

Comment: Это уже более интересно с судо???

Comment: В общем чувак подскажи какие нибудь догадки... покидай... если что то сработает из них то кину те 500)))

Comment: Давайте мне 500 рублей! Вам нужно ставить `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - на **сервере**, а не на клиенте! https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, вы забыли добавить что это ещё один "ВРЕДНЫЙ СОВЕТ" и всё же правильнее раздавать статику с того же домена куда идёт запрос

Comment: @qwabra ТС не может\не хочет поднимать сервер на 443 порту и ему *надо* использовать другой порт. Почему использование `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com` является *вредным советом*? К тому же это обычная практика, например, вы можете использовать API гугла с любого зарегистрированного сайта(другого домена), это тоже вредно? :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, у ТС клиент на плюсах, ТС хочет "защищённое соединение", ТС не понимает или понимает плохо что он делает и что ему нужно ... (в таких случаях __стоит предупреждать__).

Конечно это всё моё ИМХО и я могу сильно ошибаться, но у меня сложилось такое впечатление.

Comment: Добавлю немного ясности... dll отправляет данные в файлы на VPS сервере c интервалом в 100мсек. С этим проблем не возникло. Далее мне нужно считать данные этих файлов с сайта... То есть сайт с интервалом посылает запрос с той задачей что нужно считать эти файлы и вернуть назад ответ по ним. То есть данные вернутся тому кто и заправшивал... P/S я ставил в качестве res.header и Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com и звезду, как в статье и указывалось, но консоль пишет что ни res.set, ни res.header такой функции нет... На клиенте ставил Origin но браузер брокирует..

Comment: Тут должно быть все просто. Я бы мог сделать вывод данных в php на сервере в echo и считывать эти данные просто обращаясь по пути к php файлу с сайта, но я хочу сделать все на nodejs.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Я сегодня попробую твои рекомендации... Я прост не совсем догоняю. В указанном примере:  enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html 
нет никакого сервера... То есть из клиентской части мы просто должны обратиться к js файлу с этим кодом? и в общем то это похоже было бы на php концепцию, но если у php результатом скрипта является echo(то что вернется), то у js что является результатом выполнения?

Comment: @GlebIgorevich все уточняющие детали добавляйте в вопрос. У вас есть сервер на node.js/ Вам туда надо добавить `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, на сервер на node.js. Вот перед этой строчкой `https.createServer`

Comment: я вчера делал так примерно:
https.createServer(origin, (req, res)=>{
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // Также и домен пробовал
res.end("Ok");
}).listen(5555); // 5555 так как 443 вообще запускаться не будет

В ориджине объект с прочтенным ключем и сертификатом.

На все это он мне ответил что header функции не существует.... но вообщето странный ответ . надо бы сегодня повториь попытку.... вероятно я экспресс не верно подключил

Comment: Не вышло. header функция не найдена. с другими тоже самое... Я плохо шарю в express и не могу понять use, и прочее, но я так понимаю сервер там не создается и следовательно ничего не слушается... Неужели так сложно пингануть сервер со стороны сайта прикрепленному к нему через хостинг(((

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, пиши номер карты в общем, твоя рекомендация помогла... Да надо было Access-Control-Allow-Origin делать, но суть в том что ты мне сказал метод для access а я пишу на js. Для js функция setHeader... Все заработало. щас В ответе напишу рабочий вариант))) Ну так то... Если знаешь то все просто, хотя и не проще чем на php, но тем не менее.. А если не знаешь + еще интернет полон примером с localhost серверами то остается только перебирать варианты...

Comment: Вопрос - в вопрос, ответ - в ответ. И ошибку в нормальном виде, а не после гуглоперевода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно ставить заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - на **сервере**, а не на клиенте!

Если сервер с использованием [express](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html).

```
let fs = require("fs");
let express = require("/root/node_modules/express/lib/express");
let app = express();
let https = require("https");

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

https.createServer(options, (req, res)=>{
    req.on("data", data =>{...});
    res.end("Ok");
}).listen(5555);
```

Если сервер **без** фреймворков.

```
let fs = require("fs");
let https = require("https");

https.createServer(options, (req, res)=>{
    req.on("data", data =>{
        // Обрабатываем событие прихода данных с сайта.
    });

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    // Отсылаем данные обратно на сайт в ajax объект:
    res.end("Ok"); // Отправляем ответ обратно на сайт...
}).listen(5555);
```

Comment: А зачем вот этот заголовок? res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
Он вроде как роли не играет!?

Comment: @GlebIgorevich он играет очень большую роль. Здесь указывается, какие заголовки может отправит клиент. Если у вас клиент захочет отправить какой-нибудь кастомный заголовок, и он на сервере не будет прописан, то у вас опять будет ошибка CORS. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: Оо спасибо... Вы можете мне помочь еще с одним вопросом. Здесь больше я не могу задавать... Меня волнует тот факт, что программы запущенные на VPS сервере (а точнее мой сервер) регулярно слетают...В то время как тот же сервер на винде на локальной может работать бесконечно долго... А у меня сайт на 100% зависит от 2 серверов и их сбои не допустимы иначе сайт просто не будет делать то, для чего он предназначался.... Как заставить серверную программу на nodejs пожизненно слушать порты???

Comment: @GlebIgorevich зависит от того, почему они "слетают". Почему не можете задавать вопросы? Кстати, не забудьте принять мой ответ.

Comment: Я уже использовал 1 вчера. Сутки еще не прошли. А как принять?

Comment: Не знал, что здесь есть такое ограничение о_О. Слева от вопроса есть галочка, нажмите на нее.